# Counting the result of a left join using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the proper way to count the result of a left outer join using dplyr?

Consider the two data frames:

```
a <- data.frame( id=c( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )
b <- data.frame( id=c( 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4 ), ref_id=c( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ) )
```

`a` specifies four different IDs. `b` specifies six records that reference IDs in `a`. If I want to see how many times each ID is referenced, I might try this:

```
a %>% left_join( b, by='id' ) %>% group_by( id ) %>% summarise( refs=n() )
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

     id  refs
  (dbl) (int)
1     1     2
2     2     1
3     3     3
4     4     1
```

However, the result is misleading because it indicates that ID `2` was referenced once when in reality, it was never referenced (in the intermediate data frame, ref_id was `NA` for ID 2). I would like to avoid introducing a separate library such as `sqldf`.

Comment: Not sure why someone wants to downvote this Q&A...

Answer (score 5):

With data.table, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a); setDT(b)

b[a, .N, on="id", by=.EACHI]


   id N
1:  1 2
2:  2 0
3:  3 3
4:  4 1
```

Here, the syntax is `x[i, j, on, by=.EACHI]`.

- `.EACHI` refers to each row of `i=a`.
- `j=.N` uses a special variable for the number of rows.

Comment: really insane and xtra neat library.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some good answers but since the question asks not to use packages here is one.   We perform a left join on `a` and `b` and append a `refs` column which is TRUE if `ref_id` is not NA.  Then use `aggregate` to sum over the `refs` column:

```
m <- transform(merge(a, b, all.x = TRUE), refs = !is.na(ref_id))
aggregate(refs ~ id, m, sum)
```

giving:

```
  id refs
1  1    2
2  2    0
3  3    3
4  4    1
```

Answer (score 2):

It does require another package, but i'd feel remiss for not mentioning `tidylog` which provides reports for a wide range of tidyverse verbs. In your case, it would produce a report like:

```
library(tidylog)

a <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4 ))
b <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4), ref_id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'))

a %>% left_join(b, by='id')

left_join: added one column (ref_id)
           > rows only in x   1
           > rows only in y  (0)
           > matched rows     6    (includes duplicates)
           >                 ===
           > rows total       7

  id ref_id
1  1      a
2  1      b
3  2   <NA>
4  3      c
5  3      d
6  3      e
7  4      f
```

See [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/01/tidylog/) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidylog/tidylog.pdf) for more examples/info

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time deciding if this is a hack or the proper way to count references, but this returns the expected result:

```
a %>% left_join( b, by='id' ) %>% group_by( id ) %>% summarise( refs=sum( !is.na( ref_id ) ) )
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

     id  refs
  (dbl) (int)
1     1     2
2     2     0
3     3     3
4     4     1
```

Comment: `tally` is another option for the last step: `a %>% left_join( b, by='id' ) %>% group_by( id ) %>% tally( !is.na( ref_id ) )`

Comment: Thanks @Frank! I think `tally` is much more readable than `summarise` and it stays within `dplyr`.

Comment: Note that `tally` does not give the desired column name of  `refs` whereas `summarize(refs=...)` does.